# Access denied on file_get_contents

Tags: php, mysql

I have a free host on 000webhost and I have a MySQL database there in which I store data.

I've found out for some reason I can only connect to that database from that site. If I were to copy&paste, lets say, the index.php from that server to another, I would get access denied.

My goal is to fetch some data from that database and display it on the other server thus since direct method does not work, I've made a file on db server that will run a query locally and another file on the other server that will use file_get_contents() function to fetch the data.

load file (on server with db)

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($database)or die("cannot select DB");


$Qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dctt_users ORDER BY FirstSave");
$num = mysql_num_rows($Qry);
$Qry2 = mysql_query("SELECT TimesSaved FROM dctt_users WHERE UserName = 'Default Name' ORDER BY FirstSave");
$line = mysql_fetch_array($Qry2);
$num = $num + $line['TimesSaved']-1;
echo $num;
```

fetch file (on server that is not related to the one with mysql db)

```
$filename = "http://blink-forum.site90.com/dctt/test.php";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
echo $content;
```

And even though it does look like it should work just fine, it doesn't.

Does anyone know a solution to this or even if there's a way for me to connect directly?

Comment: Are there any errors? What's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some configuration, MYSQL only accepts connections from localhost (scripts on the same server as the database). There should be something in your control panel that says something along the lines of remote database hosts. You need to configure remote access to your DB there.

Here is a screenshot from cPanel if that is what your host uses:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, not.. only this is supported there(db overview and phpmyadmin link. [image](http://prntscr.com/8dhi6e)

Comment: My bad. According to this help article, remote database connections are disabled on the free tier. http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27

Comment: Hmm, that clears it out then. That's a big bummer though as I don't want to host the website I'm working on on that server. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (emphasis mine):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function **if the fopen wrappers have been enabled**

I bet your ultra-cheap webhost has not enabled this to prevent users from eating bandwidth scrapping sites and such. The fact the file resides on the same server is irrelevant when you request the page via http.

An alternative is to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a http request and get back the response.

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't really help me. I'd appreciate a dumbed down version as I'm not as savvy as you may think I am. Edit: tried to use cURL you posted. Didn't work; same results. "access denied" and that's it.

Comment: @blazerunner44 answered the question below. It's clear as day now. Thank you for your assistance as well as you've introduced me to curl which will help me in other ways :)